# Django dynamic file upload path

Tags: python, django, file, file-upload

Here its my django code.

I want to upload my file on specific location and that path is created dynamically.

```
def get_upload_file(instance, filename):
   today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
   directory = 'Data/'+ str(today_date)
   if not os.path.exists(directory):
       os.makedirs(directory)
   full_path = str(directory)+"/%s" %(filename)
   print "full_path --> ",full_path
   # user = updated_path()
   # print user
   return full_path


class UploadFile(models.Model):
   path = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file)
```

I am trying above code to upload file but i want to another directory in it and its name is on username.

expected output

```
Data/2015-08-16/username/
```

then i want to upload file in username directory

any solution please help me

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any exception?

Comment: I didn't get username in get_upload_file function...how can I get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution for the above problem. When I am creating class instance set request object to that instance and access that request object in get_upload_file function

```
 class UploadFile(models.Model):
       path = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file)
       reqObj = None

       def set_reqObj(self, request):
           self.reqObj = request

new_file = UploadFile(path = afile)
new_file.set_reqObj(request)
```

use reqObj in get_upload_file function

```
instance.reqObj.user.username
```

updated get_upload_file function is

```
def get_upload_file(instance, filename):
   today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
   directory = 'Data/'+ str(today_date)+'/'+instance.reqObj.user.username
   if not os.path.exists(directory):
       os.makedirs(directory)
   full_path = str(directory)+"/%s" %(filename)
   return full_path
```